# Is there a way to call a variable that is initialised later in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, session

I have this piece of code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = 'bob';
echo $_SESSION["username"];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
```

I want to replace where it says 'bob' with $username instead (which is initialised in line 6).
Is this possible?

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` is fine

Comment: it wouldn't make any sense to do so.  If username is set by the post value, then you should save it into the session there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [assigning by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign), requiring only that the `$username` variable is declared prior to assigning it to `$_SESSION['username']`:

```php
$username = 'bob';
$_SESSION["username"] =& $username; //mind the &
$username = 'foo';
echo $_SESSION["username"]; // 'foo'
```

That said, I recommend against an approach like this. Consider using `$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['username']` instead.

Comment: By using `$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['username']` I get this "Warning: Undefined array key "username"".

Comment: That was only an example. You likely still need to apply the if statement condition as shown in your original post. What I meant is that using references is discouraged. Setting `$_SESSION['username']` directly when it needs to change is preferred.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't do that.

But maybe you can change your code to:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = 'bob';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    // code
}

echo $_SESSION["username"];
```